# How can I run SqlCommand inside while(dr.read())

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm getting an error:

> *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.*

My code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM shoppingcart", con);
SqlDataReader dr;
con.Open();

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
                found = true;
                productdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(4));
                string ago1 = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", Convert.ToString(productdate));
                string productdate1 = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", Convert.ToString(ago));
                int productqty = Convert.ToInt32( dr.GetValue(3));
                int productID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(2));
                int cartID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0));
                if (productdate < ago)
                {

                    SqlCommand updateproducts = new SqlCommand("UPDATE products SET ProductQuantity=ProductQuantity+@ProductQuantity WHERE ProductID=@ProductID", con);
                    updateproducts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", productqty);
                    updateproducts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", productID);
                    updateproducts.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlCommand deletecart = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM shoppingcart WHERE ID=@ID", con);
                    deletecart.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", cartID);
                    deletecart.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
}
con.Close();
```

I need to execute update and delete inside `while(dr.read())` but that error pop up when I try to close connection then open again the while will stop and error will appear it said the `ExecuteReader` is close. please help me.

Answer (score 6):

If you add this to your connection string it will allow that code to work:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cfa084cz.aspx):

> Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that allows the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. In previous versions, only one batch could be executed at a time against a single connection. Executing multiple batches with MARS does not imply simultaneous execution of operations.

Just as a general note - it's better practice to wrap anything that implements IDisposable in a using block. That way the resources will be properly closed down and release.

So you connection can be wrapped like:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
...
}
```

Similarly with your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` objects.

Comment: damn thank you so much i've been working on this for an hour and that is all that i need. thank you so much :D

Comment: No problem @ReynanCapco, make sure to mark your answers which are answered as answered.